# How do I cover up a broken concrete landing?

Tags: concrete, backyard, landing

Before it was flipped, our house used to be two separate units. The staircase to go to the second floor was outside in the backyard. The staircase was removed by the flipper, but the concrete landing still exists there.

This landing is quite cracked/broken, and pretty bad to look at. It also takes up a decent chunk of our backyard.

What can I do to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Pictures would help.

Comment: Do you want more backyard or a deck?  Answer this question and then can help with how.  Picture of the cement might help with cover or replacement options.

Comment: Sorry, I found this from Stackoverflow, and posted while at work. I'll post pictures tonight as soon as I get home.

Comment: When you say "landing" I'm picturing something rather small, but you say it takes up a sizeable part of your yard. Would you provide measurements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't *actively want* a "concrete deck" or a "deck to hide concrete" then breaking it up and burying it is cheapest (and offers the most DIY and "I won't need a gym membership while I do this" options) while breaking it up and hauling it away offers a "pay money and make it go away" option that is very likely to cost less than building additional structure.

And either way, you are not left with a deck you really don't appear to want in your backyard.

Tool rental can make the DIY easier and quicker, and you can blend an approach of break it up yourself and have it hauled away by others, for instance. Might even get someone to come get it for "clean fill" for free.

Comment: broken concrete is clean fill,  you may be able to unload it at no cost to a pool company or landscaping supplies place etc, (you'd still need to cart it)